# want to optimize this string manipulation program c++

Tags: c++, string

I've just solve this problem:
http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=3139

Here's my solution:
https://ideone.com/pl8K3K

```
int main(void) 
{
    string s, sub;
    int f,e,i;

    while(getline(cin, s)){
        f=s.find_first_of("[");

        while(f< s.size()){
            e= s.find_first_of("[]", f+1);
            sub = s.substr(f, e-f);
            s.erase(f,e-f);
            s.insert(0, sub);
            f=s.find_first_of("[", f+1);
        }

        for(i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
            while((s[i]==']') || (s[i]=='[')) s.erase(s.begin()+i);
        }

        cout << s << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get TLE ,and I wanna know which operation in my code costs too expensive and somehow optimize the code..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This question is more suitable for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Could you make a performance estimate of your own program ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about code review.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your problem correctly, you need to rethink your design.  There is no need for functions to search, no need for `erase`, `substr`, etc.

First, don't think about the `[` or `]` characters right now.  Start out with a blank string and add characters to it from the original string.  That is the first thing that speeds up your code.  A simple loop is what you should start out with.

Now, while looping, when you actually do encounter those special characters, all you need to do is change the "insertion point" in your output string to either the beginning of the string (in the case of `[`) or the end of the string (in the case of `]`).

So the trick is to not only build a new string as you go along, but also change the point of insertion into the new string.  Initially, the point of insertion is at the end of the string, but that will change if you encounter those special characters.

If you are not aware, you can build a string not by just using `+=` or `+`, but also using the `std::string::insert` function.

So for example, you always build your output string this way:

```
    out.insert(out.begin() + curInsertionPoint, original_text[i]);
    curInsertionPoint++;
```

The `out` string is the string you're building, the `original_text` is the input that you were given.  The `curInsertionPoint` will start out at 0, and will change if you encounter the `[` or `]` characters.  The `i` is merely a loop index into the original string.

I won't post any more than this, but you should get the idea.